# передача через POST двумерный массив

Tags: php, post

Есть цикл который создает input-ы с разными именами

```
<input name="state['0']['state']"  type="text" value="">
    <input name="state['0']['id_state']"  type="text" value=""> 
    <input name="state['0']['day_send']"  type="text" value="">   
<input name="state['1']['state']"  type="text" value="">
    <input name="state['1']['id_state']"  type="text" value=""> 
    <input name="state['1']['day_send']"  type="text" value=""> 
<input name="state['2']['state']"  type="text" value="">
    <input name="state['2']['id_state']"  type="text" value=""> 
    <input name="state['2']['day_send']"  type="text" value="">
```

и так далее. Далее формой через post отправляю их обработчику.

Так вот как правильно записать код, чтобы из $_POST вытащить хотя бы первую тройку полей? Если можно то без подключения библотек, json и подобного. Только силами пхп.

Comment: Ну здесь все правильно а в `php` у вас уже будут `$_POST['sate'][0]` и `$_POST['sate'][1]` массивы.

Comment: Вы можете использовать такие имена для полей:
`<input name="state[]"  type="text" value="">`, `<input name="id_state[]"  type="text" value=""> `, `<input name="day_send[]"  type="text" value="">`. И обращаться к ним так `$_POST['state'][0]`, `$_POST['id_state'][0]`, `$_POST['day_send'][0]`

Comment: Pyramidhead Спасибо! Проблема была в том, что я использовал  пхп в имени <input name="id_state['<?=$i?>']" ...> без него все заработало!

Comment: @Pyramidhead Вынесите свой комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете использовать такие имена для полей:

```
<input name="state[]" type="text" value="">
<input name="id_state[]" type="text" value="">
<input name="day_send[]" type="text" value="">
```

И обращаться к ним так:

```
$_POST['state'][0]
$_POST['id_state'][0]
$_POST['day_send'][0]
```