# Как в переменную POST записать масcив?

Tags: php

```
for ($i = 1; $i < 2; $i++) {


$name1= $_POST[$i];


echo "Значения переменных, переданных методом POST - ".$name1 ;}
 ?>

<form action="#" method="post" name="form1" target="_blank">
<!--Текстовые поля -->
<?php  for ($i = 1; $i < 3; $i++) {
echo  '<p><input name='.$i.' type="text" size="20"></p>';
}?>
<!--Кнопка -->
<p><input name="submit" type="submit" value="Передать"></p>
</form>
```

Мне нужно методом POST принять пару значений и значения менять с помощью переменных. Как правильно записать в post переменную? Нужно ли делать name1 массивом?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/692170/186083

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, если имя сделать массивом, например `test[]`, то и на сервер придет массив.

Пример:

```
<?php

print_r($_POST);

?>
<form action="" method="post" name="form1">
    <input name="test[]" type="text" size="20" value="123">
    <input name="test[]" type="text" size="20" value="1233">
    <input name="test[]" type="text" size="20" value="123444">
    <input name="test[]" type="text" size="20" value="12553">

    <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Передать">
</form>
```

В данном случае при клике на `submit` страница перезагрузится и отобразится массив

```
Array
(
    [test] => Array
        (
            [0] => 123
            [1] => 1233
            [2] => 123444
            [3] => 12553
        )

    [submit] => Передать
)
```

Comment: а как из POST масива сделать инєкцию каторая добавляет в базу поелементно?

Comment: @дмитрокухар это лучше отдельный вопрос создай и подробно опиши что именно ты хочешь. Потому что могут быть различные варианты, начиная от SQL запроса   `INSERT` со множественным `VALUES(..)` → http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-insert-statement.aspx (смотри " insert multiple rows") и заканчивая подготовленными запросами в mysqli/PDO с циклом внутри которого выполняется `execute()`

Answer (score 2):

Да как обычно...

```
$cc=array(
    0 => array(
        '17' => 29,
        'gt' => array(
            0 => 'dfg',
            1 => '55f5',
        ),
    ),  
);

$_POST['myarray'] = $cc;

echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: myarray откуда он берется?

Comment: Это название ключа (рандомно придумал). Под этим именем можно будет найти записываемый в $_POST массив $cc